# How to calculate the doppler shift?

Tags: digital-communications, qpsk, doppler

I am writing a QPSK receiver in MATLAB. In the transmitter part, I have generated random data using `randi`, QPSK modulated and pulse shaped using a RRC filter.

The pulse shaped data is fed to Rayleigh fading channel with a Doppler frequency and added an AWGN noise (used inbuilt MATLAB functions).

In the receiver, I have introduced a sampling clock offset using MATLAB's function `resample` (e.g. transmitted samples are 500, means resample it to 530).

After adding sampling clock offset how can I find the doppler and correct it?

Comment: You build a frequency synchronizer. There's a whole lot of ways of doing that.

Comment: See this post: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/32133/phase-synchronization-in-bpsk/32138#32138